# OCI,OCILIB,ODBC wide character(wchar) support

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle-call-interface, wchar-t, wchar

Which of these libraries OCI,OCILIB,ODBC or any other support wide character strings (wchar) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCIlib does not support wchar_t when parsing a statement. ODBC does support whar_t

Answer (score 0):

OCI normally has the closest support for what Oracle supports.